# Customize view does not appear

Tags: android

When I comment out setContentView(boardView); in my Game.java my custom view in BoardView works fine and displays everything nicely... but onSizeChanged never gets called in BoardView.java... so I can't read the device width and height at runtime. If I leave setContentView uncommented onSizeChanged works... but the screen is blank!

I want to be able to read the screen width and height at runtime and set the sizes of my ImageViews at creation so they are the optimal size.

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private BoardView boardView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        boardView = new BoardView(this);

        setContentView(boardView);  // when this line disabled, it looks ok
        boardView.requestFocus();
    }

    public class BoardView extends View {
        private final Game game;
        private float width; // width of one unit
        private float height; // height of one unit

        public BoardView(Context context){
            super(context);
            this.game = (Game)context;
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            LinearLayout maincontainer = new LinearLayout(game);
            maincontainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            maincontainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            maincontainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);   
            maincontainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            LinearLayout innercontainer = new LinearLayout(game);
            innercontainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            innercontainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            innercontainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);   

            // declare a new table
            TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(game);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

            // build a grid of ImageViews in a TableLayout
            for (int f=1; f<=7; f++) {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(game);
                for (int c=1; c<=7; c++) {
                 ImageView b = new ImageView(game);
                 b.setImageResource(R.drawable.neworb);
                 b.setOnClickListener(game);             
                    tr.addView(b, 30,30);  // I'd like to not use fixed values here
                } // for
                layout.addView(tr);
            } // for
            innercontainer.addView(layout);
            maincontainer.addView(innercontainer);

            game.setContentView(maincontainer);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
            width = w/9f;
            height = width;

            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thought I solved my own problem. I was neglecting to place my my view building code withing the Overriden onDraw method. i.e.:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{

    LinearLayout maincontainer = new LinearLayout(this.game);

    // etc..
```

I was just including it within the main class and not Overriding onDraw... which you gotta do when you extend View.

Comment: ******************************
Actually, not such a good solution. Yes, it worked. But.... now I'm creating new objects and throwing them out with each screen draw. Very bad form. LogCat tells me I'm working the Garbage Collector overtime.

Comment: I stumbled here actually looking for something else, but couldn't help notice that you took the time to both post your own solution and warn future readers of its shortcomings. I won't benefit from it, sadly, but I'm sure a lot of people will. Thank you!